# Fastest way to choose 2 items from a list of 10

Tags: multi-selection, lists

What is the fastest way to select two elements from a list of about ten? Here are some constraints:

- The list elements are strings of about 5-6 words, drawn from a list
  of 600.
- The users are completing this task many times per day.
- However, the server, not the user, is choosing the ten list elements, so typing to filter the list is out.
- The users have to pick the correct two out of the list; they can't just pick two at random. Choosing the correct elements will take the user around 1 second.
- The elements can be presented on the screen in any shape or form.
- The users will be using a mouse or a keyboard.

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to UX! We'll need some more background to give you a good answer. You say that users complete this task many times a day - do they do this many times in a row, or do they switch to other tasks in between? Do they mostly use the keyboard or the mouse? Or is it a touch screen?

Comment: Really we need to know more about this. What is the decision process of the user to choose two items? Does it matter? For example if I put 100 boxes on screen - each with a different pair from the 10 items and the selection process just becomes 'click a button', then what is wrong with that? I have no doubt it *is* wrong but why in your case is it wrong. There has to be more to it than simply 'select two items from 10'. Context, context, context...

Comment: @Roger: I agree that we need more info to provide better answers, but Kevin is looking for "the fastest way", and picking 1 out of 100 is obviously not the fastest way :-)

Comment: @Roger: BTW, you can speed up your solution by reducing the number of buttons from 100 to 45 ;-)

Comment: @Jorn - 45 you're right :-) Perhaps my point could be better made by asking what exactly is wrong with a single *I'm feeling lucky* button!

Comment: Sorry Vitaly - I went to sleep just before you left your comment! They are completing the task multiple times a day, but not consecutively, and mostly using the mouse. A touch screen is an interesting suggestion however!!

Comment: @Roger: No, the ten items are "suggested" categories for an ambiguous topic and the user has to pick the two or three best ones from the ten - they can't just choose at random.

Comment: @Kevin - so the user has to consider all options. Can this be a 'difficult' decision? Would it help, for example, to be able to *discard* some items already considered *not* to be relevant - so as to reduce 'noise' when scanning the list a second or third time?

Comment: @Roger - Not really. The user has categories in mind and is picking the two or three most relevant from a list of ten which were automatically generated by a computer

Comment: @Kevin Please edit your question with the details you've provided in the comments so future answerers can see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general answer is that checkboxes indicate that multiple choices can be made and button list indicates that only one at a time can be selected. It's possible to make the checkbox being checked just by clicking the name (the click doesn't have to be on the checkbox). This will speed things up since the hit area will increase.

Comment: +1 ! And turn the other checkboxes off when two of them are selected.

Answer (score 1):

If users of the interface will do this selection many times a day, then you are able to experiment with new approaches. I mean that learnability is the main factor here and you don't have to use widely well known patterns.

Check box sounds not that good in my opinion, clicking regular checkboxes is not so easy. It's easier if the label is more than one lines long, but in this case it's not sure (5-6 words).

I recommend to use some kind of mixed technique:

- use different big sized checkboxes, not the defaults
- use reasonably big text to help users in faster choice
- after user picks 2 elements make the others even visually inactive
- clicking again on a selected element will remove the selection so users are able to choose another one

And again: you are able to experiment with different methods because of learnability.

Comment: I like the idea of using oversized elements to make scanning and selection easier, since the list is confined to ten.

Answer (score 0):

How about [mouse click to select first element] + [mouse click to select second element] + [mouse click ok-button]?

[image]

Comment: The problem here is to define the app behavior when you click on a third item before clicking "OK" :)

Comment: I think you should add a note below first list like *( i ) Select **two(2)** Item from above list.* and changed to *( i ) Select **one(1)** Item from above list.* for second image, and OK button should be disable and for 3rd image Ok button will be enable, HTH ;).